# Get the name of the source branch after an MR is merged in GitlabCI

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have a Pipeline job that needs to run only after an MR has been merged to a certain branch (let’s assume it’s `master`).

This job is supposed to make an API call to send the name of the merged source branch.

The problem I’m encountering is that `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME` will not be available on the Pipeline that runs right after the merge (since it’s not a merge request pipeline).

Is there a way (env var) to tell what was the branch that was just merged into master?

Many thanks in advance y’all!

Comment: Not in Git, but maybe in GitLab. Note that the name of the branch is unimportant in Git in general: what you want is the commit hash, not the name of a branch; branch names hold nothing of value except commit hash IDs.

Comment: You can probably do this by reading the merge commit message. The default merge commit message used by gitlab when you merge using the UI includes the source branch name in a standard way you could parse. However, this doesn't work in all circumstances (squash merges, when someone changes the message, when the branch is merged via CLI, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Better you work with hashes not with the names.

Anyway I see two options:

1. In the pipeline for the merge request save the hash/name in an artifact. The subsequent pipeline can access this artifact an read the hash/name.
2. Run a independent pipeline and read the hash/name of the previous pipeline. To do this more secure you can add tags and read the previous pipeline only if it has the correct tag.

Comment: I did not know artifacts were available across different pipelines. That would solve my issue.

Comment: Yes they are. But better would be if you got 1 Pipeline with multiple stages. The Secod stage can run automatically when Stage 1 finished. Also you can see there the artifact.